# Glassfish: There is no cluster named localhost in this domain

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I am new to glassfish and java ee programming. I am using Netbeans. When I try to deploy my web application to glassfish server, my project output shows

```
The module has not been deployed.
```

And in the glassfish server log:

```
WARNING:   There is no cluster named localhost in this domain.
SEVERE:   There is no instance named localhost in this domain.
```

Any comment would be helpful. thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

In glassfish/domains folder is there a domain called domain1 (default name). if not you need to create a new domain. if there is one then make sure under glassfish/domains/domain1 a file domain.xml points to all instances of localhost

Comment: There's no file domain.xml in that location. Should I create one? And how do I make it pointing to all instances of localhost?

Comment: No domain.xml? Maybe you never created a new domain, check out... https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/corrupted_domain_xml the default domain.xml will have localhost

Comment: There is a domain.xml inside config in that path, but its full of non-sense.